# Lua if statement using function in for loop

Tags: objective-c, lua

I'm tyring to make kind of macros by using scripts of WoW itself.
And I heard that the script of WoW is based on Lua.

Though I've used Obj-C ,Swift and C++ for several years, Embarrassingly it was quite hard to write down some code with Lua.(eventhough it was quite short.)

I'm trying to return boolean value by function for if statement in for loops.

If it was **Obj-C**, it would be like below.

```
-(void) script {
   Bool on = NO;
   NSArray* zone = [@"Feralas",@"The hinterlands",@"Duskwood"];
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++) {
      if([self clearCheck:i]) {
         NSLog(@"stone on! -> %@",zone[i]);
         on = YES;
      }
   }

   if (!on) { 
      NSLog(@"No Stone Today..");
   }
}

-(Bool) clearCheck:(int)index {
   return [C_QuestLog IsQuestFlaggedCompleted:index+44329];
}
```

And A Lua code I tried is below

```
local o,z=false,{"Feralas","The hinterlands","Duskwood"}
function f(x) return C_QuestLog.IsQuestFlaggedCompleted(44329+x) end

for i=1,3 do
   if f(i) then do
      print("stone on! -> ",z[i])
      o=true
   end
end

if not o then do 
   print("no stone today..")
end
```

What did i miss? and How Should it be?
I hope someone could help me from this difficulty...

Comment: you should explain what your problem is. if you're facing error messages or some unexpected behaviour add that info to your question

Comment: @Piglet I'm sorry for lack of information. but I couldn't explain any because I wasn't totally able to know what problem was.. In game, It just didn't work and that's all ..haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably seeing an error message like

> 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line ...) near

That's because you have a superfluous `do` in your code that "steals" the `end` you provided for the `if`. So you're short one `end` per if statement.

Remove `do` after `then`.

[Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.3.4 Control Structures](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.4)

> stat ::= **if** exp **then** block {**elseif** exp **then** block} [**else** block] **end**

Aside from that your code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Is that syntactically correct??? oh.. then it should be some other problem from WoW script.. I Appreciate it anyway!!